# How do I activate a django view as a scheduled task on pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, pythonanywhere

I am about to deploy my Django app to PythonAnywhere. I have a view (below) that cleans up all guest accounts older than a time period. I can activate this by manually going to the url (/cleanup/), however it would be nice to schedule this automatically.

I see PythonAnywhere handles scheduled tasks that ask for a path to a .py file. Is it possible to separate this view into it's own .py file?

```
    MAX_GUEST_ACCOUNT_DAYS = 30

    def cleanup(request):
    """
    Deletes all guest user accounts and their media if older than MAX_GUEST_ACCOUNT_DAYS 
    """
    # Get all guest accounts created before the limit        
    expired_guests = User.objects.filter(guest=True).filter(date_joined__lt=timezone.now()-timedelta(days=MAX_GUEST_ACCOUNT_DAYS))

    for guest in expired_guests:
        guest.delete()

    print(f"Deleted guest account(s) older than {MAX_GUEST_ACCOUNT_DAYS} days.")
    return HttpResponse(f"Deleted guest account(s) older than {MAX_GUEST_ACCOUNT_DAYS} days.")
```

Comment: I don't know about scheduling tasks this way, but in your code you can call .delete() method on your expired_guests queryset. This way it will be done in one query instead of one query for each guest

Answer (score 1):

You need to write custom management command and run it as Scheduled Task on PythonAnywhere. You may extract the code doing what you want to separate function and call it both from the view and from the management command.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/